# Javascript - equal functions do not behave in the same manner

Tags: javascript, function, window.open

If test.jpg is clicked(left mouse button) in html,

for **Code 1** : a blank page opens in a new tab. (bad result)

for **Code 2** : test.jpg page opens in a new tab. (ok)

**Code1** : used opek.window (equal to open to open.window)

```
<script>
window.opek = function(x,y,z){window.open(x,y,z)}

function onlyyou(url){
var NowWindow=window.opek('','_blank','')
NowWindow.document.write('<img src='+url+'>')
}

</script>

<img src="test.jpg" onclick="onlyyou(this.src)">
```

**Code2** : used open.window

```
<script>
window.opek = function(x,y,z){window.open(x,y,z)}

function onlyyou(url){
var NowWindow=window.open('','_blank','')
NowWindow.document.write('<img src='+url+'>')
}

</script>

<img src="test.jpg" onclick="onlyyou(this.src)">
```

For me, it looks **window.opek** is equal to **window.open**.

But why **Code 1** behaves in different way ?

Actually I create a function, containing window.open. The created function didn't work properly. So I  dig down and down, and figured out even a function that looks exactly (at least for me) the same do not work in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in your **code 1** you are not returning `window` objectback. Update your function to **return** new window and it will work:

```
<script>
  window.opek = function(x,y,z){ return window.open(x,y,z); }

  function onlyyou(url){
    var NowWindow=window.opek('','_blank','')
    NowWindow.document.write('<img src='+url+'>')
  }

</script>
```